# Excluding rightmost edge in numpy.histogram

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, binning

I have a list of numbers `a` and a list of bins which I shall use to **bin the numbers in `a`** using `numpy.histogram`. the bins are calculated from the *mean* and *standard deviation* (`std`) of `a`. So the number of bins is `B`, and the minimum value of the first bin is `mean - std`, the maximum of the last bin being `mean + std`. (The text in **bold** indicates my final goal)

An example goes like the following:

```
>>> a
array([1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 6])

>>> bins = np.linspace(mean - std, mean + std, B + 1)
array([ 0.79217487,  1.93072496,  3.06927504,  4.20782513]))

>>> numpy.histogram(a, bins = bins)[0]
(array([2, 3, 0], dtype=int32)
```

However, I want to exclude the rightmost edge of the last bin - i.e. if some value in `a` exactly equals `mean + std`, I do not wish to include it in the last bin. The caricature about `mean` and `std` is not important, excluding the rightmost edge (aka making it a half-open interval) is. The [doc](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram) says, unfortunately in this regard:

> All but the last (righthand-most) bin is half-open. In other words, if
> bins is:
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4] then the first bin is [1, 2) (including 1, but excluding
> 2) and the second [2, 3). The last bin, however, is [3, 4], which
> includes 4.

Is there a simple solution I can employ? That is, one that does not involve manually fixing edges. That is something I can do, but that's not what I'm looking for. Is there a flag I can pass or a different method I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one (kind of crude?) way to turn the make the last bin half-open instead of closed. What I'm doing is subtracting the smallest possible value from the right side of the right-most bin:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 6])
B = 3 # (in this example) 
bins = np.linspace(a.mean() - a.std(), a.mean() + a.std(), B + 1)
# array([ 0.79217487,  1.93072496,  3.06927504,  4.20782513]))
bins[-1] -= np.finfo(float).eps # <== this is the crucial line
np.histogram(a, bins = bins)
```

If you're using some other type other than float for the values in `a`, using a different type in the call to `finfo`. For example:

```
np.finfo(float).eps
np.finfo(np.float128).eps
```

Comment: Seems fair enough! The concept seems to do justice to the sense of openness in discrete terms. I used `np.finfo(bins.dtype)` to use the dtype of `bins` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Clip the array first. Do NOT use numpy.clip() function. it would just set out-bounded data to clip high/low value and counted into left bin and right bin. that would create high peaks show on both ends

Following code worked with me. My case is integer array, I guess should be ok with Float array.

```
clip_low  = a.mean() - a.std()                 # I converted clip to int 
clip_high = a.mean() + a.std()                 # should be ok with float
clip= a[ (clip_low <= a) & (a < clip_high) ]   # != clip_high (Do NOT use np.clip() fuxntion
bins= clip_high - clip_low                     # use your bins # 
hist, bins_edge= np.histogram(  clip, bins=bins, range=(clip_low,clip_high))
```